# How to call a method in fragment from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment class which contains a method called "loadSongs" that loads all the songs from external storage and displays it in the recyclerview. I want to call this method from main activity. How can I do it?

Comment: Check out the correct answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536565/call-activitys-methods-from-fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Fragment method from a parent Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903077/calling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity)

Comment: Where can I find the id for the fragment?

Comment: @SebinPaul if you don't have id give fragment a tag and retrieve using that tag

Comment: Sorry for this noobish question, but how to retrieve the tag? I have given a tag. But when I try to retrieve it gives me an error.